# <noscript> tag is causing Google structured data <script type="application/ld+json"> to not work

Tags: javascript, html, json, search, ld

I use the  tag to detect if js is disabled, and redirect to warning page if that is the case.  Here's the code:

```
<noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=nojava/index.html" />
</noscript>
```

I'm adding ld+json structured data code for Google search.  Here's the code:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">  {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "Brand",
      "logo": "https://logolink.png",
      "name": "Page-Name",
      "alternateName": "Other-Name",
      "description": "My description text",
      "image": "https://imagelink.jpg",
      "url": "https://website.com"
    }
</script>
```

The js disabled detection seems to work fine.

The structured data code works fine as a snippet in Google's structured data test tool, but it doesn't work in context of the full page in the tool or live.  Removing the js detection  tag code solves the problem (but I need that  tag code).

Important note: the presence of the  detection tag seems to tell the Google structured data code (in tool and on page) that js is disabled.  When this tag is present, the structured data tool redirects to the warning page.

I haven't seen any reports of this problem, so I'm sure I must be doing something wrong.  For example, is there a better way to execute the no js redirect than using the meta tag?

All suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where have you put the `<script>` data? In the `<noscript>` tag?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - the <script> and <noscript> tags are both in header, independent of each other.